# how to enable nvidia persistence-mode on boot for ubuntu 20.04 (server)

Tags: boot, 20.04, nvidia

Every time I try to invoke `nvidia-smi` it takes a long time for it to show up; it turns out there should be persistence mode enabled one easy way is to just call `nvidia-smi -pm 1`. But this does not enable it for boot.

How can I make it work on boot? I tried to run `sudo nvidia-persistenced` but it's the following to syslog:

```
 kernel: [  949.165626] NVRM: Persistence mode is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use nvidia-persistenced instead.
 nvidia-persistenced: Started (1994)
 nvidia-persistenced: Failed to open libnvidia-cfg.so.1: libnvidia-cfg.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
 nvidia-persistenced: Shutdown (1994)
 nvidia-persistenced: Started (1997)
 nvidia-persistenced: Failed to open libnvidia-cfg.so.1: libnvidia-cfg.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
 nvidia-persistenced: Shutdown (1997)
 nvidia-persistenced: Started (2041)
 nvidia-persistenced: Failed to open libnvidia-cfg.so.1: libnvidia-cfg.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
 nvidia-persistenced: Shutdown (2041)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install the `nvidia-driver-$version` package from the default Ubuntu repositories.  It will install the nvidia driver, the `nvidia-persistenced` binary, and start the `nvidia-persistenced.service` via `systemd`.

Run:

```
systemctl edit nvidia-persistenced.service
```

This creates an override file that changes the behavior of the default `/lib/systemd/system/nvidia-persistenced.service` file.  This will open the default editor, likely `nano`, with nothing in it.  Paste the following content:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/nvidia-persistenced --user nvidia-persistenced --persistence-mode --verbose
```

Save the file and it will automatically be created as `/etc/systemd/system/nvidia-persistenced.service.d/override.conf`.
Lastly, restart the daemon:

```
systemctl restart nvidia-persistenced.service
```

Answer (score 2):

The following helped me to resolve error and make persistence daemon:

```
sudo apt install libnvidia-cfg1-510 #replace 510 with your driver version
```

then run the following command:

```
sudo nvidia-persistenced --user USER #replace USER with your username
```

if you just want to make it presistance for **only** your current session just run this:

```
sudo nvidia-smi -pm 1
```

Comment: The OP asks how to enable at boot time

Answer (score 0):

I personally do it with crontab to launch it a boot time.

```
sudo crontab -e
```

I use Vim. Use whichever text editor you feel most comfortable with. At the end of the file add the following:

```
@reboot sudo nvidia-smi -pm 1 &
```

Save and exit crontab. Reboot, log in, open terminal and type:

```
nvidia-smi
```

If you get a line saying your GPU is ON, you're good to go.