# Cannot run docker container with --gpu all

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, docker

I am trying to run a docker container with option `--gpu all`.
It give me the error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: error running hook #0: error running hook: exit status 1, stdout: , stderr: Auto-detected mode as 'legacy'
nvidia-container-cli: initialization error: load library failed: libnvidia-ml.so.1: cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory: unknown.
ERRO[0001] error waiting for container:
```

**What is working**

- I also has issues using torch with conda, son I solved it first by re-installing cuda and torch, and it finally works fine, so **I guess the docker issue is not related to GPU drivers.**

**What I tried**

- Following this [github issue](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/issues/1648), I tried to put my gpu in persistence mode.

  - Following the first answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1400122/how-to-enable-nvidia-persistence-mode-on-boot-for-ubuntu-20-04-server), I tried to edit `/lib/systemd/system/nvidia-persistenced.service` file, but it didn't changed anything.
  - Trying another way following [nvidia documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/driver-persistence/index.html#persistence-daemon),

```
nvidia-persistenced failed to initialize. Check syslog for more details.

~$ sudo -i
root@PORT-BONNAV-l:~# nvidia-persistenced --user h.bonnavaud
nvidia-persistenced failed to initialize. Check syslog for more details.
root@PORT-BONNAV-l:~# nvidia-smi -pm 1
Persistence mode is already Enabled for GPU 00000000:01:00.0.
All done.
root@PORT-BONNAV-l:~# logout
```

Looks like it was already in persistent mode, so the problem remains.

- I checked nvidia-persistenced status

```
~$ sudo systemctl status nvidia-persistenced
● nvidia-persistenced.service - NVIDIA Persistence Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nvidia-persistenced.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/nvidia-persistenced.service.d
             └─override.conf
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2023-09-27 14:30:25 CEST; 7min ago
    Process: 12354 ExecStart=/usr/bin/nvidia-persistenced --user nvidia-persistenced --persistence-mode --verbose (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 12355 (nvidia-persiste)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 38097)
     Memory: 304.0K
     CGroup: /system.slice/nvidia-persistenced.service
             └─12355 /usr/bin/nvidia-persistenced --user nvidia-persistenced --persistence-mode --verbose

Sep 27 14:30:25 PORT-BONNAV-l systemd[1]: Starting NVIDIA Persistence Daemon...
Sep 27 14:30:25 PORT-BONNAV-l nvidia-persistenced[12355]: Verbose syslog connection opened
Sep 27 14:30:25 PORT-BONNAV-l nvidia-persistenced[12355]: Now running with user ID 129 and group ID 137
Sep 27 14:30:25 PORT-BONNAV-l nvidia-persistenced[12355]: Started (12355)
Sep 27 14:30:25 PORT-BONNAV-l nvidia-persistenced[12355]: device 0000:01:00.0 - registered
Sep 27 14:30:25 PORT-BONNAV-l nvidia-persistenced[12355]: device 0000:01:00.0 - persistence mode enabled.
Sep 27 14:30:25 PORT-BONNAV-l nvidia-persistenced[12355]: device 0000:01:00.0 - NUMA memory onlined.
Sep 27 14:30:25 PORT-BONNAV-l nvidia-persistenced[12355]: Local RPC services initialized
Sep 27 14:30:25 PORT-BONNAV-l systemd[1]: Started NVIDIA Persistence Daemon.
```

**Current status**

- Don't looks like it's a GPU driver issue.
- Don't looks like it's a persistent mode issue.
- I am able to run the docker without `--gpu all` option
- I am able to use my GPU (with torch through cuda) outside docker
  Where does this issue could come from ?

**system details**

- Ubuntu 20.04
- sudo lshw -C display output

```
~$ sudo lshw -C display
  *-display                 
       description: 3D controller
       product: NVIDIA Corporation
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=nvidia latency=0 mode=1920x1080 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1080
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:600-5ff irq:185 memory:a3000000-a3ffffff memory:6000000000-600fffffff memory:6010000000-6011ffffff ioport:3000(size=128)
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff irq:184 memory:6072000000-6072ffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff memory:4010000000-4016ffffff memory:4020000000-40ffffffff
```

- nvidia-smi output

```
~$ nvidia-smi
Wed Sep 27 14:53:26 2023       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 515.43.04    Driver Version: 515.43.04    CUDA Version: 11.7     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA T600 Lap...  On   | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   54C    P8    N/A /  N/A |    603MiB /  4096MiB |      6%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      2498      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                 86MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3590      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                203MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3785      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell               92MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      5163      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox          145MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      7384      G   ...b/thunderbird/thunderbird       67MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

- sudo lshw -c video | grep 'configuration' output

```
~$ sudo lshw -c video | grep 'configuration'
configuration: depth=32 driver=nvidia latency=0 mode=1920x1080 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1080
configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
```

Thank you in advance for any help / hint / link.